# Find the next nearest 8:00 pm from given time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Given that I have a `NSDate *timeRightNow` which is the current time.

How do I find the next 8:00 pm right from this time?

Thus, if right now were 8:01 pm I would grab TOMORROW's 8:00pm

If it were 7:59 pm, I would grab TODAY's 8:00 pm.

So it's the next upcoming 8:00.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to do everything in UTC or do you need to take local time into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vignesh has the right idea, but you can't just add seconds to a date to get another day. You need to add "one day" because there may be a time change. This is a revised version of his code to do that.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setHour:20];
NSDate *today8PM = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSDate *next8PM;

if ([now compare:today8PM] == NSOrderedDescending) {
  NSDateComponents *oneDay = [NSDateComponents new];
  oneDay.day = 1;
  next8PM = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:today8PM  options:0]
}
else {
  next8PM = today8PM;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [NSDate-Extensions](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions).

Then you can do the following:

```
#import "NSDate-Utilities.h"

NSDate *next8pm;
if ([timeRightNow timeIntervalSinceDate:[timeRightNow dateAtStartOfDay]] < 16*3600)
{
    next8pm = [[timeRightNow dateAtStartOfDay] dateByAddingHours:16];
}
else
{
    next8pm = [[[timeRightNow dateAtStartOfDay] dateByAddingDays:1] dateByAddingHours:16];
}
```

Comment: The first test can give wrong results if there is a daylight savings time transition on that day. In that case the time difference between 00:00 and 16:00 is *not* 16*3600 seconds.

Comment: And btw. the NSDate-Extensions project that you linked to makes the same error. `dateByAddingDays:` adds 86400 seconds to the date, which is *wrong*.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you wanted,

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setHour:20];
NSDate *today8PM = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

if ([now compare:today8PM] == NSOrderedDescending)
{
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dayComponent.day = 1;
dateToBeIncremented = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:dateToBeIncremented options:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateToBeIncremented );

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@", today8PM );

}
```

Comment: A day does not have 86400 seconds if there is a daylight savings time transition.

Comment: @MartinR +1.  I think you can get tomorrow at 8pm by adding 1 to the day of `components` and then getting date from it.

Comment: Yes, that would be a correct solution. - Both answers are *almost* right and can be fixed.

Comment: @MartinR,@JeremyP , Good catch. I haven't thought about the weird timezone change for daylight savings. I will edit the answer. Thanks.